# rhandsontable autocomplete dependent columns

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

the following example app starts with an empty table that the user will have to fill. I would like to add some dependecies in the values that he could choose for the column Nation and City, so, for example, if he choose Nation=Italy when he clicks on the column City only Milan and Rome should appear; viceversa if he first choose Milan only Italy should appear in the autocomplete list.
Suggestions?
Thank you

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(rHandsontableOutput("data"))

server = function(input,output) {
df = data.frame(Nation = character(),City=character(),Num_Clients=integer())
values = reactiveValues(data = df)

observe({
req(input$data)
values$data = hot_to_r(input$data)
})

output$data = renderRHandsontable({
rhandsontable(values$data, height=500, minRows=1,stretchH = "all") %>%
hot_col(col="Nation",type="autocomplete",source=c("England","Spain","Mexico"    ,"Italy"),strict=TRUE,allowInvalid=FALSE) %>% 
hot_col(col="City",type="autocomplete",source=c("Rome","Guadalajara","Madrid    ","London","Milan"),strict=TRUE,allowInvalid=FALSE)  %>% 
hot_validate_numeric(col = "Num_Clients", min = 0)

})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please see this related GitHub [issue](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/105) on cascading dropdowns.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something along this path:

```
 library(rhandsontable)
   library(shiny)

   ui = fluidPage(rHandsontableOutput("data"))

   server = function(input,output) {
     df = data.frame(Nation = character(),City=character(),Num_Clients=integer())
     values = reactiveValues(data = df)

     observe({
       req(input$data)
       values$data = hot_to_r(input$data)
     })

     output$data = renderRHandsontable({
       rhandsontable(values$data, height=500, minRows=1,stretchH = "all") %>%
         hot_col(col="Nation",type="autocomplete",source=c("England","Spain","Mexico"    ,"Italy"),strict=TRUE,allowInvalid=FALSE) %>% 
         hot_col(col="City",type="autocomplete",source=c("Rome","Guadalajara","Madrid    ","London","Milan"),strict=TRUE,allowInvalid=FALSE)  %>% 
         hot_validate_numeric(col = "Num_Clients", min = 0)

     })


     observeEvent(input$data,{

       change <- unlist(input$data$changes$changes)
       if(!is.null(change)){
         #Ifchange in the 1st column(0th Column)
         if(as.numeric(change[2]) == 0 ){#If change in country filter the city
           if(change[4] == "Italy"){#If itality is selected
             output$data = renderRHandsontable({
               rhandsontable(values$data, height=500, minRows=1,stretchH = "all") %>%
                 hot_col(col="Nation",type="autocomplete",source=c("England","Spain","Mexico","Italy"),strict=TRUE,allowInvalid=FALSE) %>% 
                 hot_col(col="City",type="autocomplete",source=c("Rome","Milan"),strict=TRUE,allowInvalid=FALSE)  %>% 
                 hot_validate_numeric(col = "Num_Clients", min = 0)

             })
           }
         }
       }

     })
   }
   shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do that for every Nation and City or, more in general, for every allowed value in 2 or more columns of a handsontable without having to use a switch for all the possible cases.

Comment: Maybe save all the nation and city in a dataframe and filter cities based on the user's selected nation?

Comment: @SBista I'm very interested by the answer you provided but I get the following warning message when I try to select a country when running your script: `shiny error in if: missing value where true/false needed`